# Modify url using javascript?

Tags: javascript, url

I'm creating dynamic image urls based on the user's screen size but
how does one modify the url so that the screen size is added at the end?

The original url pattern:

```
http://abc.net/stakes-html/images/backgrounds/2560by1440/3.jpg
http://abc.net/stakes-html/images/backgrounds/2560by1440/abcr.jpg
http://abc.net/stakes-html/images/backgrounds/2560by1440/pkjg342.jpg
```

The final url:

```
http://abc.net/stakes-html/images/backgrounds/2560by1440/3-1240by768.jpg
http://abc.net/stakes-html/images/backgrounds/2560by1440/abcr-1240by768.jpg
http://abc.net/stakes-html/images/backgrounds/2560by1440/pkjg342-1240by768.jpg
```

Comment: It's just string manipulation. Iterate over all images you want to change, access their URL and (string) replace `.jpg` at the end of the string with `-1240by768.jpg`. However, not that it might make the browser (try load) load twice as many images. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1029344/218196

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, images sizes are dynamically generated (like URL rewrite + image generator),
You can always generate image paths dynamically, as follows:

```
'http://abc.net/stakes-html/images/backgrounds/2560by1440/3-' + window.innerWidth + 'x' + window.innerHeight + '.jpg'
```

and so on, where `window.innerWidth` is current window width in pixels and `window.innerHeight` is current window height in pixels.

Anyway, consider using [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) as they allows to show an image according to users resolution **dynamically** without javascript.
Media Queries [works in all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries) right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = url.lastIndexOf(".");
var newUrl = url.substring(0, index) + "-" + window.innerWidth + "by" + window.innerHeight + url.substring(index, url.length)
console.log(newUrl); //as you can see you have the new url with the size
```